# How do I make my "alert bar" push down everything of my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote an alert bar like this:

```
alertmsg{
      font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
      font-size:135%;
      font-weight:bold;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      background-color: #fff;
      height: 56px;
      color: #000;
      font: 20px/40px arial, sans-serif;
      display:none;
      padding-top:12px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888;
      -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888;
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888;
}

function alertbar(m, timeout){
    if(!timeout){
        var timeout = 3000;
    }
    var $alertdiv = $('<div id = "alertmsg"/>');
    $alertdiv.text(m);
    $alertdiv.bind('click', function() {
        $(this).slideUp(200);
    });
    $(document.body).append($alertdiv);
    $("#alertmsg").slideDown("slow");
    setTimeout(function() { $alertdiv.slideUp(200) }, timeout);
    return false
}
```

Pretty simple. I call `alertbar("Go go go!");` to have this alert drop down.

However, it covers the body's page.  I want it to sort of "push down" on the entire page (all the elements)....sort of like StackOverflow does it I guess.

Comment: It pushes down the site because it's growing/moving the DIV -- not just making it appear. DIVs are blocking elements, so if you insert one, everything will shift. Just not slowly like seen on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's the `position: fixed` that is your problem. This will place your element relative to the window and take it out of the normal flow.

Use `position:static` (or `relative`) and make sure the `alertmsg` element is at the top of the markup.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple things you must do:

- Change the `position` CSS attribute of the "alert bar" to not be `fixed` and just be normal (remove that property).
- Change your JavaScript to `prepend` the alertdiv, rather than append it.  This will make it the first thing in the body.

  $('body').prepend($alertdiv);
- Slide your $alertdiv down normally.

Now something that you didn't take into account in your code is what happens when you run `alertbar` more than once.  You'll append more than one to the body.  If this is a concern, try doing something like this:

```
var exists = $('#alertmsg').length > 0;
var $alertdiv = exists ? $('#alertmsg') : $('<div id="alertmsg" />');
```

Now only prepend to the body if it doesn't exist already.

```
if (!exists) 
    $('body').prepend($alertdiv);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the `position: fixed` then just expand the body's top padding to the size of the alertbox.

```
$("#alertmsg").slideDown("slow", function() {
    var paddingTopStr = "+" + $(this).outerHeight().toString() + "px";
    $('body').css({ paddingTop: paddingTopStr });
});
```

You will also have to return the padding after:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    var paddingTopStr = "-" + $(this).outerHeight().toString() + "px";
    $('body').css({ paddingTop: paddingTopStr });
    $alertdiv.slideUp(200) }, timeout);
}
```

Same for the click event.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the rest of your content (to be pushed down) in a separate div and then insert your alert bar before it